# How can I delete something in a tabel with a button in the tabel

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a todo list but I can not find out how to delete something from the table using a button in the table.

this is my try

my html

```
<table id="output"></table
```

my JS

```
//variables
const out = document.getElementById('output');
// test
const tr = out.insertRow();
const cell1 = tr.insertCell(0);
const cell2 = tr.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = 'test';
cell2.innerHTML = "<button id='btn'>click</button>";
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', onclick);

function onclick(e) {
  e.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(
    e.parentElement.parentElement
  );
}
```

the programm thinks that the event parameter(e) is undefined

Comment: Are you sure it's `e` that's undefined, and not `parentElement`? I'm pretty sure events don't have an `parentElement` attribute - maybe you meant to start with `targetElement` or something?

Comment: your right it's e.parentElement but I want to delete the tr and I want it to add other tr and only want to delete the tr with the clicked button. And with e.targetElement it gives me the error e.targetElement is undefined (the same thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this change in your code. -:

```
 function onclick(e) {
      e.target
        .parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(
          e.target.parentNode.parentNode
        );
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Energieyy happy to help

Comment: Why would you use `document.getElementById(e.target.id)` instead of just `e.target`?

Comment: here is the result if you are interested : https://github.com/Energieyy/active-browser-landing-page

Comment: its the todo list at the top